# xdmOptions with remark-disable-tokenizers to disable "indented codeblock"

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

I'm creating a blog using `Next.js` + `MDX-Bundler` and trying to use [`remark-disable-tokenizers`](https://github.com/zestedesavoir/zmarkdown/tree/master/packages/remark-disable-tokenizers) to disable "indented codeblock". But i'm not able to make it work. I found a [reference here](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/993#issuecomment-932956127) which says that we can use `remark-disable-tokenizers` for this purpose.

Here is my `xdmoptions` for reference:

```js
import disableTokens from 'remark-disable-tokenizers';

xdmOptions(options) {
    options.rehypePlugins = [
        ...(options.rehypePlugins ?? []),
        rehypeSlug,
        rehypeCodeTitles,
        rehypePrism,
        [disableTokens,
            {
                block: [
                    ['indentedCode', 'indented code is not supported by MDX-Bundler']
                ]
            }],
        [
            rehypeAutolinkHeadings,
            {...}
        ]
    ];

    return options;
},
```